# Get content from javascript onClick hyperlink

Tags: java, javascript, jsoup

I'm trying to get the content from a website, that uses "onClick" instead of "href" in hyperlinks, so the url is always the same, despite of the page you are seeing.

http://www.sas.ul.pt/index.php

This is the website, and the content i'm trying to get is inside "Alimentação" > "Estudantes".

```
<a href="#" onclick="return go('','4;02');" title="Estudantes">Estudantes</a>
```

Is this possible with Jsoup?

Comment: Urgh - a whole website of inline `onClick`s? Anyway, no, that's going to be might hard, unless you understand what those `go()` function calls mean and can somehow parse them and convert them into actual URIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Jsoup.connect(url).data("nav", "index@4;02", "opt", "4;02", "chvP", "127").post();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of onclick with jsoup

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html

Just replace the line

String linkHref = link.attr("href");
with this
String handler = link.attr("onclick");

However after that there is no way to construct the URL unless you can somehow map the magic number to 4,02